# How to create "levels" in Marmalade?

Tags: android, marmalade

I would like to create a game with Marmalade, but I don't know how to make "levels" in it. I mean levels, as on Android the screens, or the activitys.

For example I don't know how to make a menu, then click on a button (I can make the button, control the touch...) and create a fully new screen for a game level.

On Android there are Activitys for this reason, but how can I do it in Marmalade?

Answer (score 0):

You can use marmalade's `IwUI` api for this. It is used for creating the UI of the game. You can either use .ui files (similar to xml files in android/xib in iOS) or can do it programmatically too.

What you need to do is, create separate `CIwUIElement*` objects which can represent complete views in your game. These can be called as you main page elements or super parent elements. You can assign childs to those super parents, such as buttons, images etc.

According to button clicks you can add or remove these super parents to the `IwUIController` and change the views according to that. You can add the elements without removing previous ones, which will result in an overlay.

You might want to create separate class for separate Super Parent element. I've created a base class for UI and subclasses to hold super parent elements. These subclasses works as an activity for me and instead of calling intent, I do add or remove them from `IwUIViewController`